# Can't add a parent folder to a file copied from a base presentation file - Insufficient Permission Error (Using Service Account)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-python-api

I am using drive_service.files().patch() method of the google python client library to **update the parent folder** for a particular file.
This file is a copy created with drive_service.files().copy() method, copying a base template google slide, and its permissions are updated to be **accessible by anyone** having the link to the file.

I am using a **Service Account** credentials for oauth2 authentication

Example -

Dest Folder - A

Original File - f1
Copied File - f2

Steps
1. Use - drive_service.files().copy() for copying File.
2. Use - drive_service.permissions().insert() - for adding permission -> type - "anyone", role - "writer"
3. Use - drive_service.files().patch({addParents: folderId}) - for adding parent folder

Steps 1 & 2 are executed successfully. Step 3 throws the following error - 

**403 - "Insufficient permissions for this file"**

The same request executed by the Google API explorer tool succeeds in creating a copy.

[Sample Link to the file I am trying to update the parents of, whose permission is set to be accessible by anyone](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1fQhfddbjqPzzlcDFHM1x2toFlIDoQGT-CDFBqpM-1jg/edit#slide=id.p3)

Is this a known issue? Is there any difference in requests being authenticated via Service Account credentials versus the Google user.

Comment: The Google API explorer worked because it used your account. The service account is not your personal account. Read more on [Creating a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) where you'll need to perform domain-wide delegation.

Comment: The service account was set up with domain wide authority. I am able to perform the file copy and permissions insert functions successfully, the only issue is with the addParents file patch operation.